# Android sqllite database lock occured when trying to insert in database from service

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

Hi I'm using broadcast receiver in service to get message and update it in db. I successfully receive messages but my problem is when ever it tries to insert in db when the activity is destroyed (but the update is happening when the app is running),it shows the following errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
05-13 04:01:46.896 4171-4171/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:274)
05-13 04:01:46.896 4171-4171/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
05-13 04:01:46.896 4171-4171/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
05-13 04:01:46.896 4171-4171/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.scanlibrary.DbHandler.addImage(DbHandler.java:132)
```

I show some of my codes
Broadcastreceiver:

```
public static class ReceiveSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public ReceiveSms(){
        super();
    }

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // receive message
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.upDateMessage(message);
    }
}
```

In MainActivity.class:

```
public void upDateMessage(String message){
    DbHandler db = new DbHandler(this,null,null,1);
    db.addImage(message);
}
```

In my DbHandler.class:

//constructor

```
public DbHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void addImage(CroppedImageClass cic){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // do some editing 
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_IMAGE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }catch (NullPointerException npe){

    }
}
```

I searched Google but I didn't found a solution to solve my problem. Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: please post `DbHandler` class, you get `NPE`, i think because you don't declare database name

Comment: i directly mentioned database name in the constructor so only I am passing null values

Answer (score 0):

You should never instantiate an activity

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

This object is not part of any life cycle, let alone in any way set up as a context.

If you want an activity or service to handle your database operation, you need to create an intent for that and call `context.startActivity(intent)` or `context.startService(intent)`. The message can be added as an extra to the intent.

Also if you do something like

```
public DbHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

remove the parameter you're not using. The constructor

```
public DbHandler(Context context, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

would suffice.

Comment: hi thank you as like said I used intents but it automatically Starts the activity but i don't want to start the activity I used Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                                    intent1.putExtra("message",content); instead of 
                                    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    context.startActivity(intent1);  instead of instantiating the activity

Comment: Why not use a service then?

Comment: yes i am using service only in service i used broadcast receiver

Comment: Still you can send an intent to the service. From there you're safe to modify the db. In BroadcastReceivers you should do as little as possible.